# what is the difference between simple sleeping (using wait_event_*() functions) and advanced sleeping (using prepare_to_wait() function)?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

In LDD3 book, it introduces simple sleeping(wait_event*() functions) and advance sleeping(prepare_to_wait() function).

If my understanding is correct, wait_queue_t seems to be a process entry but wait_queue_head_t seems to be the wait queue to store the list of processes which (wait_queue_t) are being added to..

So, it comes my confusion that what situation I should use wait_event_*() functions versus prepare_to_wait with specifying the wait process.

The only reason I can tell is that I can specify the process state before sleeping versus the simple sleeping. However, simple sleeping does offer the interruptible and uninterruptible wait_event functions..

So, I am a bit confused why we need both two from both design and implementation points of view. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This is the implementation of `wait_event()` (*much* simplified):

```c
#define wait_event(wq, condition)
{
    DEFINE_WAIT(wait);
    for (;;) {
        prepare_to_wait(&wq, &wait, TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE);
        if (condition)
            break;
        schedule();
    }
    finish_wait(&wq, &wait);
}
```

If this implementation (or one of the many other `wait_event_*` variants) works for you, then you should just use it.

However, there might be situations where you need more control over this wait loop.
For example, imagine that you want to wait for some data to be available in a buffer, and return it, and that both these operations need to be done under a lock, and that checking for the data *and* removing the data needs to be an atomic operation, i.e., both must be done under the same lock, with no unlock inbetween.
Then you would have to modify the loop above like this:

```c
void my_own_wait(...)
{
    DEFINE_WAIT(wait);
    spin_lock(&lock);
    while (!some_data_available()) {
        prepare_to_wait(&wq, &wait, TASK_xxx);
        spin_unlock(&lock);
        schedule();
        spin_lock(&lock);
        finish_wait(&wq, &wait);
    }
    take_data();
    spin_unlock(&lock);
}
```

Comment: Hi, CL. Thanks for the response. However, I it look like I still can use wait_event to put it in my_own_wait for implementation... The only difference is that I can put the condition in the while loop instead of using the condition argument in the wait_event()...

Comment: In the real world, things tend to be even more complex than `my_own_wait`; and the same applies to `wait_event` (it uses `condition` multiple times). However, if your code *does* work correctly with `wait_event`, by all means use it.

Comment: According to ldd3 there is a race unless you wrap your `schedule()` in an `if(!some_data_available())`. (In the case where some data became available, and someone tried to wake us up, after the while check and before prepare_to_wait()) http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-6-sect-2

Comment: @ted See what's three lines above the `schedule()`.

Comment: @CL To my understanding the problem is as follows: `while` checks the condition and there is no data available, so you enter the loopbody. Now *BEFORE* `prepare_to_wait` the data becomes available, and we would be woken. However, we are *not* in the wait queue yet. After this `prepare_to_wait` is executed, putting the task to sleep (setting the state to `TASK_xxx`. At this point. we missed the wake up for the data item as it was before prepare_to_wait and let our thread sleep. Note how in your first code snippet, the condition check is between prepare_to_wait and schedule.

Comment: This means, that after `prepare_to_wait` the condition is checked, and if the condition is fulfilled already, `finish_wait` is called, without calling schedule, setting the Task state to `TASK_RUNNING`, and schedule is never, called, which means the task does not actually sleep.

Comment: This code assumes that the `wakeup()` is done under the same lock.

Comment: What's the use of `wait_queue_head_t wq`?

Comment: @r0ei To ask a new question, use the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: @CL. No need to ask a new question. Just wanted to know how you declared `wq`. Nvm anyway.